# Execute code when video has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, video

I'm working on a website that uses websites to inform the visitor.
After they watched the video, I would like to send the user to another page to continue their visit.
Is it possible to catch some kind of event in Javascript or ASP.NET so I can execute some code afterwards?

This html tag is playing the video (not that it's very important)

```
<video id="player" controls="controls">
            <source src="../data/introduction.mp4" />
</video>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

Using this code, I was able to execute code after the video had finished playing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function setup() {
        var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

        video.onended = function (e) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        };
    }
    $(window).ready(setup);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just target your video ID `"player"` and use the `"ended"` parameter and you'll be fine, as easy as this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('ended',myPlayer,false);
    function myPlayer(e) {
        if(!e) { e = window.event; }
        // do something here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but the code didn't entirely work. I've altered your code a bit to work flawlessly. Great job anyway!